# for-each loop error

Tags: java

Java For-each-loop: I am trying to map the data retrieved from the operation below and mapping it to an object model. Unfortunately, it outputs only the last object from the retrieved object. Please can anyone check what could be the problem with the code.

```
public void listAllFilesInTheDirectoryAndSubdirectories(String aDirectoryName){ 
    AppDirectory appdirectory = new AppDirectory();
    PictureFile picturefile = new PictureFile();

    ArrayList<AppDirectory> subdirectories = new ArrayList<AppDirectory>();
    ArrayList<PictureFile> picturefiles = new ArrayList<PictureFile>(); 

    appdirectory.setName(aDirectoryName); 
    appdirectory.setPictureFiles(picturefiles);
    appdirectory.setSubDirectories(subdirectories); 

    File directory = new File(aDirectoryName); 
    //get all the files from a directory
    File[] allFiles = directory.listFiles();
    //Using a for-each loop to loop through each file in the list of files returned 
    for (File file : allFiles){ 
       //Check if the file is-a-file, then print it out          
       if (file.isFile()){

           String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
           String fileName = file.getName();
           String folderName = file.getParentFile().getName();

           if(folderName.equals(aDirectoryName)){

               System.out.println("Directory Name is : "+appdirectory.getName());
               System.out.println(folderName);
               System.out.println(fileName);
               picturefile.setName(fileName);
               picturefile.setType("jpeg");
               picturefile.setLength(2354); 
               Dimension dimension = new Dimension(656, 413);
               picturefile.setSize(dimension);
               picturefile.setLength(50023); 

               appdirectory.addPictureFile(picturefile); 


            }else{
              //appdirectory.setName(folderName); 
              //picturefile.setName(filePath); 
              //appdirectory.addPictureFile(picturefile); 
              //subdirectories.add(appdirectory);                  

            }         

    }else if(file.isDirectory()){
        listAllFilesInTheDirectoryAndSubdirectories(file.getAbsolutePath());

    }

 }
   // System.out.println(picturefiles.size()); 

    for(int x = 0; x<appdirectory.getPictureFiles().size(); x++){
      System.out.println(appdirectory.getPictureFiles().get(x).getName());

    }
```

}

Comment: Did you try debugging using IDE?

Comment: In addition here are the methods used to add the pictureFile to the ArrayList of picture files.                                      public ArrayList<PictureFile> getPictureFiles() {
        return this.pictureFiles;
    }
                                                                     public void addPictureFile(PictureFile pictureFile){
       this.getPictureFiles().add(pictureFile); 
    }

Comment: @Wand Marker: Yes, The code is fine. There are no bugs. ...got to be from addition of the Picture Object to the ArrayList of picture files. It only takes the last picture file that was retrieved.

Comment: edit your question to update code.. not in comments! Not everyone reads comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Move this line

```
PictureFile picturefile = new PictureFile();
```

inside the loop, or else you're only updating the one element.

Comment: Thanks! ..never noticed that mistake. Guess I am getting really tired now. THANKS AGAIN!